# Spring boot with spring data jpa. How can i perform partial update of entity from request body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Basically, i have REST controller class with update method.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Account update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Account account){
     .....
}
```

When request body only have part of fields of Account object, how can i perform partial update of account object of given id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do a get by id?  Once you have the original version, you can update it with the new object, if the properties are defined?  Something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Account update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Account account){
    Account acc = dao.getById(id);
    acc.copy(account);
    dao.update(acc);
}

class Account {
     ....
    public void copy(final Account account) {
         if (account.prop1 != null) {
             this.prop1 = account.prop1;
         }
         // update the mutable fields
         .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Basically, i wanted some high level spring methods(i.e. accountDao.mergeNonNull(acc, account), i dont know :) ) Is there something like this?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.